# How do I use scipy and matplotlib to fit a reverse sigmoid function

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have some data points which I was successfully able to graph, but now I would like to fit a curve to the data. I looked into other stackoverflow answers and found a few questions, but I can't seem to implement them. I know the function is a reverse sigmoid.

I would like to use this hill equation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr3j9.jpg

So far I tried to use the `curve_fit()` function from the `scipy` package to find the parameters but my code always breaks.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1, 1.90, 7.70, 30.10, 120.40, 481.60, 1925.00, 7700.00])
y = np.array([4118.47, 4305.79, 4337.47, 4838.11, 2660.76, 1365.05, 79.21, -16.40])

def fit_hill(t,b,s,i,h):
    return b + ((t-b)/(1 + (((x * s)/i)**-h)))

plt.plot(x,y, 'o')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()

params = curve_fit(fit_hill, x, y)

[t,b,s,i,h] = params[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fit_hill should have 6 parameters. 
(see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

fit_hill(x,t,b,s,i,h). 
You should try to give an initial guess for parameters.

For example in your model, when x=0, the value is t. So you can set the value at x=0 as an estimate for t.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([1, 1.90, 7.70, 30.10, 120.40, 481.60, 1925.00])
y = np.array([4118.47, 4305.79, 4337.47, 4838.11, 2660.76, 1365.05, 79.21])

def fit_hill(x,t,b,s,i,h):
    return b + ((t-b)/(1 + (((x * s)/i)**-h)))

plt.plot(x,y, 'o')
popt,pcov = curve_fit(fit_hill, x, y,(4118,200,1,1900,-2))
plt.plot(x,fit_hill(x,*popt),'+')

plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Have you drawn your model to visualize if it is suitable for you data ?

s and i, used only in s/i could be replaced with one variable in your model.

Comment: Thanks, I completely passed over x. I think I need to take a break and go to bed, and your inputs fit the data well.